# How can I allow a command to be used without braces around its argument, when the argument has an argument?

Tags: macros, expansion

I've defined a couple simple macros to make my life a little easier:

```
\newcommand{\curl}[1]{\ensuremath{\nabla\times #1}}
\renewcommand{\v}[1]{{\ensuremath{\vec{#1}}}}
```

This way, in text mode I can write `\v{F}` or `\curl{\v{F}}`, and all is well.

But for simplicity, at least in math mode, I'd like to be able to just write `\curl\v{F}`, and have it expand to

```
\ensuremath{\nabla\times {\ensuremath\vec{F}}}
```

just like `\curl{\v{F}}`. Since I've defined `\curl` in a pretty simple manner, this currently looks right. However, I think I'm actually getting a stranger behavior: if I change the definition of `\curl` to have parentheses, like `{(\ensuremath{\nabla\times #1})}`, then the vector symbol shows up over the closing parenthesis, as if the `\v` (but not its argument) is being captured as an argument to `\curl`.

Strangely, though, simply typing `\ensuremath{(\nabla\times {\ensuremath\vec})}` results in errors.

What's going on here? Is there a good way to do this, and is it a good idea?

(By the way, the reason I have an extra pair of `{}` in the definition of `\v` is that it allows me to use `\int_\v{x}` rather than `\int_{\v{x}}`. This much seems to work, but I'm not really sure why.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do that in normal math mode if you define

```
\newcommand{\curl}{\nabla\times}
\newcommand{\v}{\vec}
```

Then `\curl\v{F}` will do exactly what you need but, unfortunately, not for subscripts.

It's possible to make this work for subscripts, actually, but I don't think it's worthy using it (besides it's wrong because it fixes spaces when not used for a subscript):

```
\makeatletter
\def\curl{\bgroup\@ifnextchar\v\@curlv\@curl}
\def\@curlv#1#2{\nabla\times\vec{#2}\egroup}
\def\@curl#1{\nabla\times #1\egroup}
\makeatother
```

Now `$\int_\curl X$` or `$\int_\curl\v{F}$` will work. But only if `\v` follows `\curl`, not something like `\curl\mathbf{X}`. So this is error prone and not recommendable at all.

Your overuse of `\ensuremath` is wrong: it doesn't add to typing speed being able to write `\curl\v{F}` instead of `$\curl\v{F}$`.

Comment: Why does `_\v{f}` work as a subscript instead of being interpreted as `_{\v}{f}`?

Comment: With *your* definition, `\v` has a pair of braces that will delimit the subscript; I prefer mine, but  `\newcommand{\v}[1]{{\vec{#1}}}` will allow a syntax like `_\v{f}`.

Comment: I'm sure I just don't understand how expansion works yet, but when I see `_\v{f}`, I would think that expands to `_{...contents of \v...}{f}`. When/how does the `{f}` argument replace the `#1` inside of `\v`?

Comment: The key is that, when TeX scans `_`, it expands the following token until finding something unexpandable before starting to typeset the subscript; so it really sees `_{\vec{f}}`.

Comment: So `\v{f}` counts as one token? Or is it just that when `\v` is expanded to yield `#1` it eats the `{f}` argument?

Comment: When a macro is expanded it needs to look for its arguments and absorbs them.

Answer (score 11):

The simple answer here is going to be 'you cannot'. TeX is not a functional language, so `\curl\v{F}` is not 'curl of v of F'. `\curl` will absorb one token or 'balanced text' (braced group) as an argument. So `\curl\v{f}` ends up with `\curl` grabbing `\v`, then all sorts can go wrong.